# IntelliJ Idea highlighting depending on file structure; NOT file extension

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a little problem: in the project are exists several *.conf files. But they have different file structures: one of them is XML (e.g. Resin conf) and another is java `properties` file.

Is there any way change highlighting manually, or even better - to change highlighting type automatically ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems, it's impossible. I've tried to bind one file extension to some file types at the same time and failed - IDEA replace them

Comment: Then you have to remove this check in Idea's source code (only in community edition) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. IntelliJ seems to use the file extension to determine how to highlight file contents.

Is it possible to rename the files? Having the same extension for different file types seems like a bit of a bad idea.