# Choose editor depending not only on file extension

Tags: intellij-plugin

Is it possible to use a different editor in IntelliJ depending on file contents (or at least file name) instead of just file extension? [IntelliJ Idea highlighting depending on file structure; NOT file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555142/intellij-idea-highlighting-depending-on-file-structure-not-file-extension) says it isn't, but perhaps it has changed in last 6.5 years?